# How to get nepali characters from url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

My URL is like:

```
index.com/controller/method/उ-अहिले-कहाँ-छ-त
```

I tried to echo the parameter, But it looks like:

```
E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%81-%E0%A4%9B-%E0%A4%A4
```

I want the parameter to be showed as `उ-अहिले-कहाँ-छ-त`, Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code what have you tried?

Comment: In model its
function get_single_post($slug) {
    echo $slug;die();}
$slug is sent from view and it is sent to model by controller

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); is already enabled. But i got no help from that too.

Comment: @NabinKunwar Just curious, why did you use Hindi instead of Nepali in question?

Comment: @Console just to make things easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`rawurldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) function:

```
$string = '%E0%A4%89-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%81-%E0%A4%9B-%E0%A4%A4';

echo rawurldecode($string);
```

Output:

```
उ-अहिले-कहाँ-छ-त
```