# Decode a URL that contains Hindi characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, urldecode

I am creating the category slug in CodeIgniter and sending the category name in get parameter and using in my function to get the name of category. Name of category is in hindi language.

I have used php decode functions like: `utf8_decode()`, `urldecode()`, `rawurlencode()`. But it's not giving me the actual sting.

URL: `http://www.website.com/category/संस्कृति`

```
public function index($args)
{
    pr($args);
    $utf_urldecode = utf8_decode(urldecode($args));
    pr($utf_urldecode);
    $utf = utf8_decode($args);
    pr($utf);
    $rawurldecode = rawurldecode($args);
    pr($rawurldecode);
    $encode = urlencode($args);
    pr($encode);
    $dencode = urldecode($args);
    pr($dencode);
    die();
}
```

Output I am getting from each function:

```
%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF

????????

%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF

à¤¸à¤‚à¤¸à¥à¤•à¥ƒà¤¤à¤¿

%25E0%25A4%25B8%25E0%25A4%2582%25E0%25A4%25B8%25E0%25A5%258D%25E0%25A4%2595%25E0%25A5%2583%25E0%25A4%25A4%25E0%25A4%25BF

à¤¸à¤‚à¤¸à¥à¤•à¥ƒà¤¤à¤¿
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [rawurldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) will help?

As wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207769/1923681) it works.

Comment: @user3260234 It works in my test case: https://eval.in/103817
Since you're checking the result on the web page, make sure the page has UTF-8 character encoding.